# Flask routing request url based on request body?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

How can I route request based on the request body in flask? I think I can use `redirect` but I prefer not to use that and to route request immediately based on the content of the body.

Here is what I tried but failed:

```
# I am using Flask-restful extension
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

class RouteA:
    def post(self):
        return {'route': 'RouteA'}
class RouteB:
    def post(self):
        return {'route': 'RouteB'}

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app) # This is just flask-restful app wrapper extension

# I am trying to use before_request
@app.before_request
def routing():
    request_body = request.get_json(force=True)
    type = request_body.get('type', None)
    if type and type == 'RouteB':
        # somehow direct to routeB
        request.path = '/jobs/routeb'
        # I can do this too but I prefer direct routing rather than redirecting
        # return redirect(location='jobs/routeb', code=307)


# routing here
api.add_resource(RouteA, '/jobs')
api.add_resource(RouteB, '/jobs/routeb')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

How I will make request to that endpoint:

```
import requests

url = 'http://localhost:5000/jobs'

payload = {
    'type': 'RouteB'
}

r = requests.post(url=url, json=payload)
response = r.json()
print(response)
# Expecting:
# {'route': 'RouteB'}
```

Comment: `I prefer not to use redirect`. Is there any specific reason?

Comment: might result in too many re-requests. It is also cleaner if I can do direct request rather than redirection.

Comment: if you don't want to use `redirect` then run function directly in `routing`. But without `redirect` web browser will not display new url

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by running function directly in routing?

Comment: normally execute function like `return RouteA().post()`

Comment: @furas ah alright. But yeah like you mentioned, the new endpoint will not be displayed. Is there any method that will just let me modify the request's `url` or `path` property? if I have multiple rerouting, I would have to do multiple ifs in the `before_request` function.

Comment: you have `redirect()` for this - it sends message to browser to change url.

Comment: @furas I think I might have found a way to get around it. Looks like  request object in flask is immutable. So I created a middleware in which I modified the WSGI's environment variables and change the `PATH_INFO`. This enable the request path to be modified and directed to proper route.